# Javascript | String date formatting from 4-6-2014 to 2014-06-04

Tags: javascript, string, date, format, type-conversion

I need to code dates in this format: `4-6-2014`
to dates in the following format: `2014-06-04`
so i can then construct a date with it.
My approach is:

```
  var date_string = '4-6-2014'; 
  date_string = date_string.substring(6, 10)+'-' + ('0'+date_string.substring(3, 5)).slice(-2) +'-'+ ('0'+(date_string.substring(0, 2))).slice(-2);
  var new_date = new Date(date_string);
```

This code, only works if the string has double-digit days and months, once the string has no leading 0 for days or months it fails..

What would be the solution to this mess...

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simpler `(yyyy, mm, dd)` constructor:

```
var date_string = '4-6-2014'; 
var tmp = date_string.split("-");

var new_date = new Date(tmp[2], +tmp[1] - 1, tmp[0]);
```

(Swap `[0]` and `[1]` is 6 is the day part)